# unexpected end of file bashrc

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

When I open a terminal, I get:

```
line 106 unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
line 120 syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

`bashrc` has

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
*i*) ;;
  *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt 
below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; 
turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal 
window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
# We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
# (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
# a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
color_prompt=yes
else
color_prompt=
fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\
[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
 PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
;;
*)
;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval 
"$(dircolors -b)"
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
#alias dir='dir --color=auto'
#alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo 
terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-
9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
. ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
#line 106 this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
. /etc/bash_completion
fi
fi

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

There is no line `120`! The last line I have is `119` .
I tried to figure out where the problem was but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Are those `s remnants from formatting?

Comment: sorry , I deleted it

Comment: Ok, please add your full `~/.bashrc`

Comment: the error on line]120 is the result of the error on line 106

Comment: What is the `line 106 # this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile` line? Is that actually in your file? Do you have the words `line 106` there as you show?

Comment: @heemayl i posted all i have in bashrc

Comment: @terdon no i just remark that for you , there is no words line 106

Comment: @Rinzwind do you mean that line 120 because of 106 ?

Comment: For those types of error you may use http://www.shellcheck.net Copy and paste your code and it points you directly to those errors (beside a lot of improvement tipps).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is line 93:

```
alias ll='ls -alF
```

You're missing the closing quote (`'`). That should be:

```
alias ll='ls -alF'
```

The error you are getting is confusing because bash sees the opening `'` and then tries to find a closing one, and that confuses its parser completely. Just fix the missing `'` there and you should be fine.

It is complaining about line 120 because it searches all the way to the end of the file (so last line + 1) and doesn't find its closing quote.

Comment: yes, that's right . thanks, really i'm on this problem for a week searching !

Comment: This and the coloring helps in pinpointing the problem

Comment: @Rinzwind yeah, since the OP hadn't tagged with bash, there was no coloring.

Answer (score 1):

If real reason is not able to found for this error, then better to copy the original `.bashrc` from `/etc/skel/.bashrc` and do the updates carefully one by one.

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```